# How to implement notification about updates from server?

Tags: android

My Android application needs to get notification from server about new updates, so what is the solution to implement this?

Comment: you can ask the gods of the interwebs to magically throw glitter to the space and all the users that need the update will jump in joy as they all receive the notifications.

Comment: Too many possible answers? or too long for answer? look Aviad's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is somethings big.. You can check GCM

Here a link.. http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes this question is big, but I just need general idea, so your answer is what I want, thanks!